# React native. Как использовать навигацию в компонентах?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api, react-native, navigation

Пытаюсь разработать небольшое приложение, связанное с картой.
Хотелось бы использовать некоторые компоненты как у Яндекс GO. А именно первый экран, который идет вместе с картой. Или это кастомный вертикальный ScrollView?

Хотелось бы также узнать, как можно использовать Stack навигатор или другой навигатор поверх карты?
То есть, у меня есть

```
`<View>
<Mapview></Mapview>
<Cars/>
</View>`
```

В компоненте Cars отображается ScrollView. Как можно сделать так, чтобы был навигатор?
То есть, я мог передвигаться между компонентами, но на заднем плане все также оставалась карта?

Пробовал вместо  ставить CarsNavigator,в котором был StackNavigator, но таким образом даже ScrollView не отображался.

Опять же, аналог движения подсматривал в Яндекс GO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал следующую библиотеку:
react-native-bottom-sheet
Она позволяет создавать именно такие компоненты, которые мне были нужны.
По поводу навигации, то просто буду использовать дополнительные компоненты с закрытием всплывающего окна.